# SharePoint online custom list options

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, list, jquery, list-form

We are currently using SP2013 with many custom lists. I have been using JQUERY to build them.

My question is what is my options to rebuild the lists in SharePoint online?

Can I use JQUERY again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use classic experience in SharePoint Online, you can still use JQUERY & custom scripts in team sites.

If you are going to use the modern experience:

1. For list form customizations: You can use Power Apps customized forms, conditional formula to show/hide fields, JSON to format the list forms
2. For list view customizations: You can use column & view formatting with JSON Or SPFx extensions

If you need to develop any complex solution in SharePoint online modern experience then you have to use SPFx web parts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.